# startActivity() in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to create an application that calls the sender of an SMS as soon as the smartphone receives an SMS.
This is my code:

```
    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
               // ... (Managing SMS)
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
               intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + sender));
               intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
               context.startActivity(intent);
            }
    }
```

But it dials and calls the sender only when the application is in foreground, while I'd like it to work always. Using the debugger, the execution flows, but it is unable to start the ACTION_CALL activity somehow. Am I missing anything? Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android 10, there are limitations on when/how background processes (`Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`) can launch activities. This is your problem.

See [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I see I might overcome it by making the app a device owner or using SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW, hope it will work in this way

Comment: Oh yas it works by doing so

Answer (score 1):

> while I'd like it to work always

That is not an option on modern versions of Android. [You cannot start an activity from the background](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts), because you do not know what is going on in the foreground at the time. For example, if the user is relying on a navigation app for driving, taking over the foreground could cause the user to crash.

You could [raise a high-priority `Notification` instead](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/time-sensitive).